# Closing JOptionPane after input option selected

Tags: java, swing

I am using a JOptionPane and I want it to automatically close after a user has selected an option.
At present this is working but I still have to manually click the OK button to close the JOptionPane. Is there anyway I can close it when the checkbox is ticked

```
JPanel a1 = new JPanel();
        a1.add(bubbleCheckBox);
       a1.add(quickCheckBox);
        a1.add(insertionCheckBox);
        a1.add(selectionCheckBox);
      //  a1.add(mergeCheckBox);

        arraySize=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number of elements would like to sort (Recommend max =30)"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a1, "Choose an algorithm to run", DEFAULT_OPTION);

    }

    public static void lockCheckboxes(JCheckBox a) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (a == insertionCheckBox) {
            selectionCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            quickCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            bubbleCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            mergeCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
       SortAnimator.setArraySize(arraySize);
       SortAnimator animator = new SortAnimator(new InsertionSorter());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly complicated.

First, add an `ActionListener` to your `JCheckBox`'s...

When this `ActionListener` is triggered, you need to find the window which contains the `JCheckBox`, you need to find the instance of the `JOptionPane`, call `setValue` and pass it `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` then dispose of the dialog

Something like...

```
JPanel a1 = new JPanel();

JCheckBox bubbleCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Bubbble");
JCheckBox quickCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Quick");
JCheckBox insertionCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Insert");
JCheckBox selectionCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Select");

ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
        JOptionPane op = (JOptionPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JOptionPane.class, cb);
        if (op != null) {
            op.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(cb).dispose();
    }
};

bubbleCheckBox.addActionListener(al);
quickCheckBox.addActionListener(al);
insertionCheckBox.addActionListener(al);
selectionCheckBox.addActionListener(al);

a1.add(bubbleCheckBox);
a1.add(quickCheckBox);
a1.add(insertionCheckBox);
a1.add(selectionCheckBox);
//  a1.add(mergeCheckBox);

if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, a1, "Choose an algorithm to run", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Yeah for me");
}
```

Personally, I'd use a `JComboBox` and just make the user select <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd>